# Поле обязательно для заполнения 2

Tags: input, html, javascript

Здравствуйте всем! Нужна помощь. Есть скрипт валидации на обязательное поле. Скрипт работает правильно, и в нужном случает выдает ошибку. Но если не вводя текст в это поле, а сразу нажать на кнопку субмит, то кнопка срабатывает и страница перезагружается. Не могу сделать так, чтобы в случае не заполнения или неправильного заполнения поля кнопка не срабатывала. Сам скрипт:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $('.text').val('');
    $('#userName').blur(function(){
        $('#userName').removeClass();
        var nameLngth = $('#userName').val().length;
        if(nameLngth <= 1){
            $('#userName').addClass('notValid');
            $(this).next().text('Введите пожалуйста ваше имя');
        } else {
            $('#userName').addClass('valid');
            $(this).next().text('');
        }
    });
});

<form name="reg">
<input type="text" value="" name="fi" class="text" id="userName" />
<div class="error"></div>
<input name="submit" class="fbutton" value="Регистрация" title="Регистрация" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410063/how-can-i-listen-to-the-form-submit-event-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

blur + submit

**html:**

```
<form id="signup" action="/echo/json/">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" value="">
    <div class="error"></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Регистрация" title="Регистрация">
</form>
```

**js:**

```
$(function(){
    var $signup = $("#signup"),
        $username = $signup.find('#username'),
        $error = $signup.find('.error');
    
    $username.blur(function(){    
        validate($username, $error);
    });
    
    $signup.submit(function(e) {   
        e.preventDefault();    
        if (validate($username, $error)) {        
           $.ajax({
               url: $signup.attr('action'),
               success: function(){
                   alert('Вы это сделали!');
               }
            });
        }        
    });
    
    function validate($username, $error){
        if (!$username.val().length) {
            $error.text('Введите, пожалуйста, ваше имя').show();
            return false;
        }    
        $error.hide();    
        return true;
    } 
});
```

[Смотрите результат](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/11jtugga/)

#### Обновление

[Пример без ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/11jtugga/2/)

Comment: @LADYX, у Вас "тихий" ужас. Кроме того, я писал, исходя из вашего примера - форма с одним полем `username`.

Comment: > то открывается новое окно с текстом "вы это сделали"

@LADYX: При нажатии на кнопку "регистрация", если поле не заполнено, то выводится ошибка, в противном случае производится ajax-запрос. При его успехе, выводится сообщение "Вы это сделали!". Вы разве ajax-запрос не планируйте? 

Вот [пример без ajax](http://jsfiddle.net/romeoz/11jtugga/2/) + добавил класс `invalid`

> В смысле тихий ужас?))

 * html-элементы не кэшируется в переменные, т.е. каждый раз производится их поиск
 * нелогичное название `id` и `class`: `userName` и `notValid`
 * сложная и неоправданная логика: `$(this).next()`

Comment: @LADYX, если необходимо выводить ошибку, когда меньше двух символов, то:

    if ($username.val().length <= 2) {
      ...
    }